# Работа с PointCollection при рисовании

Tags: wpf

Имеется реализация рисования ломаной и многоугольника на `InkCanvas` с помощью `PointCollection`:

```
private void inkCanvas1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
if (polylPressed)
{
    SolidColorBrush Brush = new SolidColorBrush(ColorP1);
    Polyline Polyline1 = new Polyline();
    Polyline1.Stroke = Brush;
    Polyline1.StrokeThickness = PolyLSize;

    polylinePoints.Add(e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(inkCanvas1));
    Polyline1.Points = polylinePoints;
    inkCanvas1.Children.Add(Polyline1);
}

if (polygPressed)
{
    var Str = new SolidColorBrush(ColorP1);
    var brush = new SolidColorBrush(ColorP);
    Polygon Polygon1 = new Polygon();
    Polygon1.Fill = brush;
    Polygon1.Stroke = Str;
    Polygon1.StrokeThickness = PolyLSize;

    polygonPoints.Add(e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(inkCanvas1));
    Polygon1.Points = polygonPoints;
    inkCanvas1.Children.Add(Polygon1);
}
}
```

Однако, есть проблема: при рисовании, к примеру, ломаной, и дальнейшем переключении для рисования многоугольника, сам многоугольник рисуется от последней точки ломаной. А при очистке коллекции сама ломаная/многоугольник удаляется с `inkCanvas`. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён: при нажатии на кнопку для рисования ломаной забыл присвоить булевой переменной `polygPressed` значение `false`, и наоборот.